# Data/list transpose with python(ironpython)

Tags: python, arrays, list, ironpython

I have a datalist(see top data example in image , first 3 rows)
I want data transformation(kind of stranspose/stack) in format(see bottom data example in image)

[image: example data]
[example list transpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZZjX.png)

The emty(in red) fields must be deleted in the proces.
I've no idea where to start. Need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the start.
I've short script that's all i needed for now.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel("data.xls", sheet_name='data')`

melted_df = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Header col 1','Header col 2','Header col 3'])
clean_df = melted_df.replace('', np.nan).dropna()
clean_df.to_excel("clean-df.xls", sheet_name='clean data')
```

This script is based on .xls files

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with pandas. You didn't provide the exact input file so I had to try to make a replicate.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'objectType':['x', 'y'], 
    'property1':['TestA11', 'TestD11'], 
    'property2':['TestA21', 'TestD21'],
    'property3':['TestA31', ''],
    'property4':['TestA41', ''],
    'property5':['', 'TestD51'],
    'property6':['', 'TestD61'],
    'property7':['TestA71', 'TestD71'], 
    'property8':['TestA81', 'TestD81'], 
})

melted_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['objectType'], value_vars=list(df.columns)[1:])
```

Output should look like this:

```
        variable     value
0   x   property1   TestA11
1   y   property1   TestD11
2   x   property2   TestA21
3   y   property2   TestD21
4   x   property3   TestA31
5   y   property3   
6   x   property4   TestA41
7   y   property4   
8   x   property5   
9   y   property5   TestD51
10  x   property6   
11  y   property6   TestD61
12  x   property7   TestA71
13  y   property7   TestD71
14  x   property8   TestA81
15  y   property8   TestD81
```

And then to remove the empty value row, you could do something like this:

```
clean_df = melted_df.replace('', np.nan).dropna()
```